# 1st order phase transition, superheating/supercooling, metastable state

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, phase-diagram

I read that superheating and supercooling characterize 1st order phase transitions in papers. Some of them also use the metastable state at the same time as the superheating/supercooling. Are metastable states and superheating/supercooling the same thing, or if not, how do they relate?

Are they just features of a 1st order phase transition?

Can anyone share any hints or some references to explain this in detail?

Comment: A supercooled liquid is metastable compared to the solid in that the liquid's free energy is now higher than the solid phase, and one is just waiting on kinetics to allow the phase transition to occur (it will be a long wait for diamond to turn into graphite).  There are also metastable phases which do not appear on an equilibrium diagram (c-49 vs c-54 titanium silicide).  Though similar I think of them a little differently. That is a more materials-science perspective.  It is, of course, related to @Jonas's answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, these terms are related. Metastability usually comes about in systems which are described by a [Landau free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_theory) which contains a cubic or power 6 term on top of the usual [$\phi^4$-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_interaction). E.g. the Landau free energy with a cubic term is shown below.

There are three special temperatures:

- $T^{**}$ at which an additional local minimum forms at finite $\phi$.
- $T_c$ at which this local minimum becomes the global minimum.
- $T^*$ at which the curvature at $\phi=0$ becomes negative.

Let the system start at $\phi=0$ (disordered phase) for $T>T^{**}$. Upon lowering $T$ below $T_c$ the finite $\phi$ local minimum would be the favorable one. But the curvature at $\phi=0$ is still positive, so it stays in the disordered phase; it is said to be supercooled. Lowering the temperature further, the curvature eventually becomes negative and the $\phi=0$ phase becomes unstable, so $\phi$ jumps at the finite value of the local minimum. When raising the temperature again, the (ordered) finite $\phi$ phase will stay stable (positive curvature at the local minimum) even when the temperature exceeds $T_c$; the system is superheated, then. Once $T>T^{**}$, again, the local minimum at finite $\phi$ disappears and $\phi$ jumps back to zero.

As $\phi$ jumps, this is a discontinuous, a.k.a. first-order, phase transition. Metastability is the umbrella term describing both supercooling and superheating. In magnetic systems, this is also referred to as *hystersis*.

More information on this can be found e.g. in *N. Goldenfeld: Lectures on phase transitions and critical phenomena*, chapter 5.5. This is also a good introduction to Landau theory in general if you are not familiar with it.

[image: Landau free energy with cubic term]

Comment: It is very clear explain to me, thanks a lot. @Jonas But if I can ask a further question regarding to the example you mentioned the magnetic system, does a second order phase transition can have the hystersis effect? I have seen in a paper(http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.20.1915), the hystersis cycle appears in all cases in the Fig.1. Cases (a) to (c) with a deep hystersis cycle are claim to be 1st order phase transitions, but cases (d) and (f) with a smaller hystersis are claim to be second order phase transitions.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is very confusing in that respect. First-order transitions are only one situation were hysteresis-like behavior can occur. In magnets specifically, it is more complicated than that and one needs to take into account crystal defects. I did not read the entire paper you linked and cannot say what specifically triggers the hysteresis there.

Comment: Just want sure if the hystersis effect is only the feature of a first order phase transition. But I think I understand now it is also possible for a second order phase transition.

Comment: Is the picture from the book you referred to? Thx

Comment: @HonzaZubáč, no the picture was created by a friend who was so kind to typeset the lecture notes for our course.

Comment: I don't see the explanation about the negative curvature effects in Goldenfeld 5.5, and I've never heard of it explained like this. I thought that the discontinuous jump would occur when T=Tc if you cooled slow enough (as in enough time fluctuations in the system exploring its phase space will allow it to eventually find the other global $F$ minimum (and then from that point in phase space it is even more unlikely to return to the original minimum)